# Whose Law do we follow?

Tags: support, policy, copyright

Whose copyright rules do we abide by here?

Wikipedia's [list of parties to international copyright treaties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_parties_to_international_copyright_treaties) outlines five major international copyright treaties, which apply in various combinations to various countries.  We seem to be a US-centric site, so I currently assume we follow US copyright law in specific in addition to any international treaties the USA has ratified.  Is that the case?  Why?

Comment: Related: [What constitutes copyright infringement?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/357/what-constitutes-copyright-infringement) and [Copyright details about RPG.SE](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/2845/copyright-details-about-rpg-se)

Comment: For which purposes? As creators, holders, licensors, licensees, or otherwise-users of IP? (These may all vary.)

Answer (score 7):

Looking at [legal](http://stackexchange.com/legal): US Laws and international treaties.

> All materials displayed or performed on the Network, including, but not limited to text, graphics, logos, tools, photographs, images, illustrations, software or source code, audio and video, and animations (collectively, “Content”) (other than Content posted by Subscriber (“Subscriber Content”)) are the property of Stack Exchange and/or third parties and are protected by United States and international copyright laws.

...

> All trademarks, service marks, and trade names are proprietary to Stack Exchange and/or third parties. Subscriber shall abide by all copyright notices, information, and restrictions contained in any Content accessed through the Services.
>
> The Network is protected by copyright as a collective work and/or compilation, pursuant to U.S. copyright laws, international conventions, and other copyright laws. Other than as expressly set forth in this Agreement, Subscriber may not copy, modify, publish, transmit, upload, participate in the transfer or sale of, reproduce (except as provided in this Section), create derivative works based on, distribute, perform, display, or in any way exploit, any of the Content, software, materials, or Services in whole or in part.

...

> 15. Copyright Policy
>
> Stack Exchange has adopted the following policy toward copyright infringement with respect to the Network in accordance with the Digital Millennium Copyright Act. The address of Stack Exchange's Designated Agent for copyright takedown notices (“Designated Agent”) is listed below.

Comment: The terms of service that bind users and Stack are US jurisdiction, but that's not what's relevant to the Stack's use (via our actions) of *others'* IP, which I believe is the question at hand.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Section 15 does. Otherwise, like usual, the question needs to be clarified as to the specific (meta) problem at hand?

Comment: The DMCA doesn't (can't) cover interactions with non-US copyright regimes though, and the Stack *is* bound by international copyright laws as it operates internationally (and afaik, though being not a lawyer of course, that this is a well-established international law precedent).

Comment: Question of standing. Company is quartered in the US, therefore is liable in the US. Servers are in the US (only, ... ?), therefore to sue the servers, all action happens in US courts.

Comment: Berne Conventions and others stipulate harmonising and cooperation though. So the US is obliged to enforce claims made by treaty partners. Hence, Stack in practice cares about lots of copyright regimes when using IP.

Comment: Please clarify the question then such that it references available rules on the stack so I can ping community about specific questions. Right now, it reads like a request to /legal.